# Find rows that have different value on a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get all the `user_id` that are having different `user_ip_address` on `user_device` table using a MySQL query.

```
Table: user_device

id    user_id    user_ip_address
-----------------------------------
1        1        1.1.1.1
2        1        1.1.1.1
3        2        2.2.2.2
4        3        3.3.3.3
5        1        10.10.10.10
6        4        4.4.4.4
7        2        20.20.20.20
8        3        3.3.3.3
```

In this data, `user_id 1` and `user_id 2` have different `user_ip_address`.
It should output `1` and `2`

I tried:

```
SELECT user_ip_address AS c
FROM user_device WHERE user_ip_address IN (SELECT user_id 
FROM user_device group by user_id having user_ip_address!=c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
select  user_id 
from user_device
group by user_id
having count(distinct user_ip_address) >1;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> user_id
> 1
> 2
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d858cf8d1f6616a0fe9e08cda2314201)

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of different addresses each user has:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_device
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_ip_address) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
select user_id 
from (
  select user_id
  from user_device
  group by user_id, user_ip_address
) 
group by user_id
having count(*) > 1
```

should give you in theory user_id = 1 and 2